# A matrix $A \in k^{n \times n}$ of rank $1 \leq r \leq n-1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and let $A$ an $n \times n$ matrix over $k$, with $n \geq 2$,
$A \in k^{n \times n}$.

Assume that $1 \leq rank(A)=r \leq n-1$; this means that $A$ has:

- $r$ $k$- linearly idependent rows
- $r$ $k$-linearly independent columns
- invertible sub-matrix $B \in k^{r \times r}$ of maximal order

> **Question:** Is it possible to obtain additional properties if we further assume that every possible sub-matrix of order $r$ is invertible?
>
> In view of Amateur_Algebraist's comment, I would like to divide this question to two cases: **(i)** $|k| < \infty$; **(ii)** $|k|=\infty$.

Notice that the additional assumption not always holds, for example:
$ A=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, $n=4$, $r=2$.

Any comments are welcome; thank you!

Comment: It seems that such $A$ should have only few zeros, maybe at most $n \choose r$ zeros; for example, if $n=4, r=2$, then $A$ has at most $6$ zeros.

Comment: This means the $r$-th compound matrix of $A$ is entrywise nonzero. I am not sure what significance this has in general, but I can think of some special cases. E.g. when $k=GF(2)$ and $r=n-1$, $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ must be the all-one matrix. Therefore both $\ker(A)$ and $\ker(A^T)$ are spanned by the vector of ones, which means every row/column of $A$ contains an even number of ones.

Comment: @user1551, thank you for you comment! Interesting. Please, could you elaborate  more in an answer?

Comment: What kind of properties do you want? If $|k|<\infty$, this is an equivalent definition of a generating (or "parity-checking", for that matter) matrix for a [maximum distance separable linear code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDS_matrix). See e.g. MacWilliams, Sloane "The Theory of Error-Correcting Codes".

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist, thank you for your comment! I am not familiar with the result you mentiond, sounds interesting! So I will divied my question to two cases: $|k| < \infty$ and $|k|=\infty$. You can write your idea as an answer, if you like. I was lookung for results in the spirit of linear algebra results concerning determinants, linear dependence etc., but other properties (like you mentioned) are welcome too.

Comment: Let $A=X_{n\times r}Y_{r\times n}$ be a rank decomposition. That all $r$-rowed minors are invertible means that any $r$ rows of $X$ are linearly independent and any $r$ columns of $Y$ are linearly independent. This doesn’t seem particularly interesting if $k$ is infinite. In fact, if $k$ is infinite and $X,Y$ are chosen at random, it is almost always the case that all $r$-rowed minors of $A=XY$ are invertible. So, you probably want to focus on the case where $k$ is a finite field.

Comment: @user1551, thank you very much fot your nice explanation. Do you think that there exists a similar condition relevant for infinite $k$?

Comment: To be frank, I have no idea what you are looking for. There are classes of matrices defined by the properties of minors, but usually these properties involve minors of *all* orders. Some examples are [totally positive matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_positive_matrix), [totally unimodular matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix) and [Sylvester’s criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion).

Comment: @user1551, thank you very much for your ideas and help. I will continue to think about my question and try to figure out what I am looking for more precisely. Thanks again.